# Problem of resizing Map using SwiftUI Mapkit

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I would like to zoom in my map on the application, I tried both using `latitudinalMeters: 300`, `longitudinalMeters: 300` or spin with `latitudeDelta: 0.001`. Both of them did not work at all.

I also chose `(0, 0)` as my center, but every time I run on the simulator, I have `(37.326010,-122.026056)` as my center. Apparently, none of the default settings of center and region that I had set in my location manager works in ContentView.

Here is my code of **LocationManager.swift:**

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject{
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    @Published var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    override init(){
        self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 0,longitude: 0),latitudinalMeters: 300, longitudinalMeters: 300)
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}


extension LocationManager : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 300, longitudinalMeters: 300)
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

Here is my **ContentView**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapView2()
    }
}

struct MapView2: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        let coord = locationManager.location?.coordinate
        let lat = coord?.latitude ?? 0
        let lon = coord?.longitude ?? 0
        return VStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $locationManager.region,
                interactionModes: .all,
                showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for SwiftUI using MapKit, I would not use the CoreLocation framework. You can use the `.onChange` modifier to perform zoom changes to your View. You can use the `@State var zoom` with a SwiftUI gesture to perform them if you want, or anything that can do those changes live. I added two buttons within a slider to zoom in or out for the example.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    MapsView()
  }
}

struct MapsView: View {

  @State var zoom: CGFloat = 15

  @State var mapCoordinate = MKCoordinateRegion(
    center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
      latitude: 38.989202809314854,
      longitude: -76.93626224283602),
    span: MKCoordinateSpan(
      latitudeDelta: .zero,
      longitudeDelta: .zero))

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {

      Map(coordinateRegion: $mapCoordinate)
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)

      // You can see the changes being operating by the .onChange modifier.
      Slider(value: $zoom,
             in: 0.01...50,
             minimumValueLabel: Image(systemName: "plus.circle"),
             maximumValueLabel: Image(systemName: "minus.circle"), label: {})
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .onChange(of: zoom) { value in
          mapCoordinate.span.latitudeDelta = CLLocationDegrees(value)
          mapCoordinate.span.longitudeDelta = CLLocationDegrees(value)
        }
    }
    .font(.title)
  }
}
```

Comment: your code works well, but when I want to track user's location by adding argument into map: `Map(coordinateRegion: $mapCoordinate, interactionModes: .all,
          showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow))
          .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all) ` No matter how I scorll the bar, the zoom level will remain back, that is also the key point of my question, how can I fix this so that the zoom level can be changed during tracking? Thank you!!

Comment: Instead of having a constant in the `userTrackingMode` parameter, can you declare this `wrapper`: `@State var userTrackingMode: MapUserTrackingMode = .follow` and add it to the `userTrackingMode` parameter as follow: `$userTrackingMode`. More on that, do you test your location on a real device and not on the simulator?

Comment: wrapper values work, can you please explain why and how this works out rather than using a constant inside parameters? I used a simulator and I do the city-run, I haven't tried running on real device

Comment: As View as set on struct, SwiftUI needs to redraw the entire struct when values update. A wrapper value is used to tell the SwiftUI view of its changes. When that happens, in this example, MapsView will redraw itself, which you will have your view updated accordingly to the new value. When using a constant, and for the SwiftUI view, the value never change, so it doesn't need to redraw the view regarding this value. Use constant when a value never ever change in your view, or you can use it in the preview to populate fake data.